# Убрать span при адаптации экрана

Tags: html, css

Нужно при уменьшении экрана, убрать как то в css span внутри кнопки, чтобы осталась только иконка.
Подскажите как это сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 200px) {
  .header-btn__back span { 
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

Естественно, подставьте свои нужные значения в медиа-запрос.